# Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32) when creating update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am getting this error after I add a trigger to a table: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32). Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tu_PeopleGeneral
   ON  dbo.PEOPLEGENERAL
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @PeopleCodeID nvarchar(10)
    Select @PeopleCodeID = i.People_Code_ID from inserted i

    UPDATE PEOPLEGENERAL SET PICTURE_NAME = RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME)
    WHERE PEOPLE_CODE_ID = @PeopleCodeID

END
```

I want a trigger that will trim any spaces from the end of the data that the user is attempting to update. I have a similar insert trigger that works just fine. I'm not sure why it will not work for updates.

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: MS SQL SERVER is being used.

Comment: They meant to add the tag to your question

Comment: Oh, of course. I will add that.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why your attempt doesn't work, but have you considered using an `instead of insert` trigger instead of `after insert` and changing the data before it is inserted?

Comment: Aside... your trigger assumes that there will only ever be one row. Triggers can get executed for 0, 1 or many rows - you need to treat the `inserted` virtual table as a table, because it is, and use set-based operations.

Comment: Have a read through [Remarks for DML Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql#remarks-for-dml-triggers). I'm guessing you also have an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on this table that is retriggering itself and so going recursive.

Comment: Do you have an `UPDATE` trigger also? If so please show. Note that your trigger is fundamentally flawed due to the issue mentioned by @AlwaysLearning see also https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/

Comment: And the solution is mentioned in the duplicate: `IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL( OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytrigger') ) > 1 RETURN;`

Comment: Sorry. Just realized I copied the insert trigger and posted it instead of the update trigger. Here is the update trigger:

Comment: You still have similar problems, there's nothing stopping you from updating the same table. I suggest two things: add : IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN at the start of the trigger. Remove the variable and join your inserted table so you only update the changed data. And finally, don't trim if it's already trimmed. Trigger_nestlevel is just a bandaid IMHO